# Regex display with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, regex, list

So I have a regex question. When running this code

```
           if (str1.trim().contains(search2)){
                String str3 = str1;      
                str3 = str3.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
                System.out.println("location: " + Arrays.asList(str3.trim().split(" ")));
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
```

it produces 
      `location: [290, -70]`

is it possible to replace the bracket characters with "[ x, x]" with "x x" so that they just show the characters within quotes?

`location: "290 -70"`?

I'm kinda new to regex so I tried some things like `.replace("[", " ");` but it did not work.

EDIT ----

Here's my entire code.

```
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("/Users/Dannybwee/Documents/workspace/csc199/src/csc199/test.txt"));
    String str;

    List<String> finallist = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null){
        finallist.add(str);
    }

    String search = "node";
    String search2 = "position";


    for (String str1: finallist) {
        if (str1.trim().contains(search)){
            System.out.print("{ key " + str1+ ",\n" + 
                                "name: " + str1 + ",\n" +
                                "Truth: 'Tainted'," + "\n" +
                                "False: 'NotTainted, \n");
        }


        if (str1.trim().contains(search2)){
            String str3 = str1;      
            str3 = str3.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
            System.out.println("location: " + Arrays.asList(str3.trim().split(" ")));               
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do is take a text file, and then change the formatting of the text. I thought it would be easiest to take the file and scan for what needed to change. for instance, All I want is to change the brackets outputed above to braces.

So basically I want it to output `location: "290 -70"` instead of `location: [290, -70]` without the comma and brackets

Comment: The square brackets from the array aren't part of the value, so `replace()` won't do anything to them. What's the big picture of what you're trying to do here? Why are you creating an array in the first place? What's your original input?

Comment: In line 4, it looks like you're splitting a string into a list, and then from your question, I'm getting that you want to output the list, without the brackets? What does `str3` look like before you split it? Could you just print it as is?

Comment: Can you specify input and output clearly ?

Comment: so my input is a text file, here's my code. I take a textfile and then put each line as an index of an array. I want my output to be 

location: "290 -70" instead of location [290, -70]

Comment: What is `str3` *before splitting it*? In other words, why did you split it at all?

Comment: @mypetlion what I'm doing is scanning an entire list for a certain word in the line. The specific line I'm working with is position = (0 -0); Once it finds this line, I just want to print out the (0 -0) rather than the other characters

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm splitting because the line is positions = (number number); 
What I'm trying to do is just extract the number from that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm splitting because the line is `positions = (number number);` What I'm trying to do is just extract the number from that index

Then if you split, you get `["(number", "number)"]`.

You want to remove the round brackets, not the square ones. And you have already done that `[^-?0-9]+` removes all characters but one or more `0-9`, `-`, and `?`

You don't need to split anything.

```
    if (str1.trim().contains(search2)){  
        str1 = st1.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
        System.out.println("location: \"" + str1 + "\"");               
        System.out.println("}");
    }
```

You could also forget the regex entirely and use `str1.substring(1, str1.length() - 1)`

By the way, if you are trying to produce JSON, it isn't valid. The keys need to be quoted

Comment: This works. Instead of println("location: \"" + str1 + "\"");  you replace str1 with str3.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You never needed `str3` unless you use `str1` again after that if statement

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the literal bracket with the backslash "escape character" `\[`. This is common for many regex entries that also correspond to triggered characters.
`\\` , `\.` , `\(` ... etc

It is important to note that in Java we must escape our escape character, therefore whenever you use it you'll need a single backslash for each backslash:
`\\[`, `\\\\`, `\\.`, `\\(` ... etc

You can implement this into your existing code, or you could make your life a little easier by using a pattern matcher.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D+?(-?\\d++)\\D+?(-?\\d++)\\D*");        
Matcher m = p.matcher(STRING);
String results = "location: "+m.group(1)+" "+m.group(2);
```

`\\D+?` eliminates non-digit (0-9) characters reluctantly, this will spare the '-' when found.

`(-?\\d++)` will capture m.group(n) which will possessively contain as many digits as it can find in a row. Since the '-' was spared earlier it should be present for this capture if at all.

Comment: `str3` doesn't have brackets... `Arrays.asList(str3.trim().split(" ").toString()` does

Comment: @DarkRain It isn't since it doesn't remove correctly `]` and it only matches an open bracket followed by non-numbers, then one or more close brackets

Comment: Sorry, forgot double escape in java.